# What are "non-union states"?

Tags: united-states, employment, civil-law, corporate-law

I'm watching a lecture by Robert B Reich.

He's talking about a hypothetical case in which Bob, a CEO of some corporation, wants to "move the US plant to a non-union state" to reduce wages.

I understand that the benefit, for employers, is that since employees aren't organized in a union, they have less bargaining power over their employers.

My question is:

What are "non-union states"?

Are these states (in the US) that don't allow workers to unionize? But I've read that there's a "National Labor Relations Act (NLRA)" that guarantees the right of workers to unionize, so this can't be...

Comment: There are also places in the US where unions are more and less powerful, due to social differences more than legal ones.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to ask Reich what he personally was talking about. There is a distinction within the US between states which prohibit mandatory union membership versus allow mandatory union membership. In about half of the states, a union cannot force an employer to accept a contract which obligates that a person join the union. These are known as [right-to-work laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-work_law). No state requires all workers to join a union, and no state forbids the formation of unions.